# Flexbox layout issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, materialize

Using this style guide: [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/), my page layout is like:

```
<header>
<main>
<footer>
```

[Based on this article](http://materializecss.com/footer.html), I'm using the following CSS for a "sticky footer"

```
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

All browsers except Internet Explorer show the webpage with no problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Older versions of IE don't support flex :(  http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox isn't supported as standard on IE versions prior to IE11: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

However, you can add the `-ms-` prefix to get support on IE10. Your code would be as follows:

```
body {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: hmmm not sure then.. from what i can see, it seems to be working on 11, is this how it should look? http://imgur.com/ILvgnBM